# Google Sheets Nested Query with Aggregate Function

Tags: google-sheets, count, nested, aggregate

I am trying to use the COUNT() function inside a nested query for Google Sheets. Here is the query I am using: `=query('Salary Data'!B3:J35000, "SELECT '"&query('Salary Data'!B3:J35000, "SELECT COUNT(E) WHERE E >= 1000000")&"', COUNT(E) WHERE E >=900000 AND E < 1000000")`

The query outputs 'count' for the result of the nested query instead of the count of salaries >= 1000000. How do I get the actual count from the subquery?

EDIT: It seems the subquery only returns the name of the aggregate function used, whether it is count, max, min, avg, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be

```
={query('Salary Data'!B3:J35000, "SELECT COUNT(E) WHERE E > 90000 and E >= 1000000"),query('Salary Data'!B3:J35000, "SELECT COUNT(E) WHERE E >= 1000000")}
```

*I really don't understand what you expect!*

Comment: Your solution is doing what I expected, so thank you for your help. I will try to explain better what I was expecting. When I try to pass a subquery, without an aggregate function (i.e. SELECT B), I get the expected answer. When I try to use COUNT in the subquery, I get the word 'count' as the answer. I expect the answer to be a number, and not the name of the function

Comment: So, if everything is ok, pls acept the answer and close the topic. Thx for your explanation.